# QListWidget with custom widgets

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyqt5, qlistwidget

I need to create a list of custom drawn messages. After failing with `QStyledItemDelegate` for reasons described in this question [QStyledItemDelegate's option is not updating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67356159/qstyleditemdelegates-option-is-not-updating) I am trying to use `QListWidget` for this. However I don't understand how should I change the size of widgets in it. For example, I narrow down the window, so the widgets have to gain height, but the `sizeHint` function of my custom widget is called only twice in the beginning and never after that. This is the minimal reproducible example, which I use:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import (
    Qt,
    QSize,
    QRect,
    QRectF,
)
from PyQt5.QtGui import (
    QPainter,
    QFontMetrics,
    QFont,
    QTextDocument,
    QTextOption,
    QPen,
)
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (
    QApplication,
    QListView,
    QMainWindow,
    QListWidget,
    QListWidgetItem,
    QWidget,
)

frame_width = 0

class MessageWidget(QWidget):

    def __init__(self, msg):
        super(MessageWidget, self).__init__()
        self.msg = msg
        self.font = QFont("Times", 14)

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        field = QRect(0, 0, self.width(), self.height())
        doc = QTextDocument(self.msg)
        doc.setDocumentMargin(0)
        opt = QTextOption()
        opt.setWrapMode(opt.WrapAtWordBoundaryOrAnywhere)
        doc.setDefaultTextOption(opt)
        doc.setDefaultFont(self.font)
        doc.setTextWidth(field.size().width())
        field.setHeight(int(doc.size().height()))
        field.setWidth(int(doc.idealWidth()))
        painter = QPainter(self)
        painter.setPen(Qt.gray)
        painter.setFont(self.font)
        painter.translate(field.x(), field.y())
        textrectf = QRectF(field)
        textrectf.moveTo(0, 0)
        doc.drawContents(painter, textrectf)
        painter.translate(-field.x(), -field.y())

    def sizeHint(self):
        print("Here")
        global frame_width
        doc = QTextDocument(self.msg)
        doc.setDocumentMargin(0)
        opt = QTextOption()
        opt.setWrapMode(opt.WrapAtWordBoundaryOrAnywhere)
        doc.setDefaultTextOption(opt)
        doc.setDefaultFont(self.font)
        doc.setTextWidth(frame_width)
        return QSize(0, int(doc.size().height()))


class Dialog(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        global frame_width
        super(Dialog, self).__init__()
        self.setMinimumSize(int(QApplication.primaryScreen().size().width() * 0.1), int(QApplication.primaryScreen().size().height() * 0.2))
        self.resize(int(QApplication.primaryScreen().size().width() * 0.3), int(QApplication.primaryScreen().size().height() * 0.5))
        self.messages = QListWidget()
        frame_width = self.messages.size().width()
        self.message_array = []
        self.message_array.append("qwerty qwerty qwerty qwerty qwerty qwerty qwerty qwerty qwerty qwerty qwerty qwerty qwerty qwerty")
        self.message_array.append("abcdef")
        for i in range(len(self.message_array)):
            item = QListWidgetItem()
            widget = MessageWidget(self.message_array[i])
            item.setSizeHint(widget.sizeHint())
            self.messages.addItem(item)
            self.messages.setItemWidget(item, widget)
        self.messages.setResizeMode(QListView.Adjust)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.messages)

    def resizeEvent(self, event):
        global frame_width
        super(Dialog, self).resizeEvent(event)
        frame_width = int(self.messages.size().width())

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
window = Dialog()
window.show()
app.exec_()
```

I am not sure if I am using items and widgets properly here, but as I said in this example "Here" (printed in the beginning of `sizeHint`) is only printed 4 times when the program is started. And then no matter how I resize the window, `sizeHint` isn't called, and hence size of widgets isn't modified.

Comment: The "hint" has no defined behavior (Qt does not promise even to use it) as it is a hint. May or may not be even requested. Try to specify the size for the widget explicitly as well. When the parent widget knows the explicit size then it may request a hint too.

Comment: @AlexanderV should I specify the size of widgets or the size of items? And how should I do it? Using the `resize` method?

Comment: Yes, Vlad, make sure there is  a size. Usually minimum size is working with the hint.